# Text Box Overlapping Image

Tags: html, css

I am stuck at making the code
I want a text box to be displayed on the top-middle of the image overlapping the image. 
Can any body help me figure it out?
Thanks in Advance!!!

---

Comment: Please share your html and css code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to include your HTML and CSS into your post as this will help others to give you directions on where you are going wrong. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. But as a welcome present here's a small demo on how you can achieve this. Adjust my code as you see fit.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper .text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.wrapper .text-wrapper .text {
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250, .5);
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/2YaYxhHvcDahSwh9mlWp4-ZYYb8=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/GettyImages-482252-001-570a81d93df78c7d9edc0d78.jpg">
  <div class="text-wrapper"><div class="text">your text here</div></div>
</div>
```